# Sql server not responding, timeoutexpired

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm usign mobile for insert rows into a local sqlserver.
Some times the sql server doesnt responde and i'm forced to wait for getting exception.

I have set sqlConnetion time out to 3 seconds

```
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = " + MyIp + "; Initial Catalog = database; user id = sa; password = 1234;Connection Timeout=3");
```

The problem is that sometimes i need to wait 30 seconds.
This time as i can understand is cmd execute timeout.

```
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into customers(Name) values(name123)",con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

So first question Sql connection time out doesnt include both of them?

Second question if sql doesnt responde then why dont i get first exception in 3 seconds?

And last question why sql server sometimes doesnt responde over network?
Can it be big network(traffic) delay , between mobile and server?

Comment: "why sql server sometimes doesnt responde over network? " is not really answerable in the confines of StackOverflow. It's off-topic and not reproducible; the best you might get is a series of steps to help identify the cause. That question probably should go to Server Fault

Answer (score 1):

The timeout that you define on the SqlConnection is only applied on the connection. It won't affect any command.

You can change the timeout of the command by doing

```
cmd.CommandTimeout = 30;
```

Unfortunately, I can't help you with the last question.

Answer (score 0):

All in one here and someone will probably provide more detailed information but essentially the timeout you are setting is just one of MANY timeout settings that exist at different layers. Some of those layers are on the SQL server side, some are in the .Net framework side and some are user set like yours on the actual connection. Figuring out WHICH timeout setting is taking precedence can be a challenge.

More importantly though is WHY this operation is taking so long. What you provided should be fast enough that none of this should even be an issue. It does not get any simpler than what you are trying to do which should be almost instantaneous. I can assure you it is NOT the SQL server itself, unless you have literally billions of records in that table with every column indexed and even then I doubt its the server spending all this time on the query and has to be something in the transport. There is no way we can troubleshoot that with just the info provided.

Comment: I just wondering that in 30 seconds my query it should execute right? Thats why i start to thinking that my problem isnt the execution or sql server. Is there possibility to be sql server bug (Sql 2008 r2) over network? Or should i set port, after ip adress? Example 192.xxx.xxx.xxx,1433. Maybe Server blocks me for some reason

Comment: just wondering that in 30 seconds my query it should execute right? - Absolutly
Is there possibility to be sql server bug (Sql 2008 r2) over network? - no way in hades, millions of devs would have already ran into this a decade ago, sql server practically runs the world.
Or should i set port, after ip address - > does not matter.
I wish I could give you something more but sounds like some network troubleshooting is in order. if this is mobile how is the cell network coverage where you are testing?